# JavaScript Array filling(one to many)

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript. Could you help me to make from this array:

```
[ [ '00011111', 'ADMIN' ],
  [ '00033333', 'ACTIVITY' ],
  [ '00022222', 'SUPPORT' ],
  [ '00011111', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00022222', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00033333', 'MEMBER' ] ]
```

This one:

```
[ [ '00011111', 'ADMIN', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00033333', 'ACTIVITY', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00022222', 'SUPPORT', 'MEMBER' ] ]
```

Thank you in advance.
Would be nice if you could suggest several variants :)

Comment: I take it the number is some form of ID?

Comment: yeah, it's like id

Comment: Is this always the case? Two rules for each id ?

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: there could be more then one, two rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by checking if the common key is in the result array, then push the value or push a new array to the result set.

```js
var array = [['00011111', 'ADMIN'], ['00033333', 'ACTIVITY'], ['00022222', 'SUPPORT'], ['00011111', 'MEMBER'], ['00022222', 'MEMBER'], ['00033333', 'MEMBER']],
    result = array.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = r.find(([key]) => k === key);
        if (temp) {
            temp.push(v);
        } else {
            r.push([k, v]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Impressive way of using JS api's. But performance wise not recommended, as the second loop is finding the index every time.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Simple strategy with for loop

```
var src = [ [ '00011111', 'ADMIN' ],
[ '00033333', 'ACTIVITY' ],
[ '00022222', 'SUPPORT' ],
[ '00011111', 'MEMBER' ],
[ '00022222', 'MEMBER' ],
[ '00033333', 'MEMBER' ] ];
var dest = [];

var intermediateObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < src.length; i ++) {
    if(!intermediateObj[src[i][0]]) {
        intermediateObj[src[i][0]] = [];
    }
    intermediateObj[src[i][0]].push(src[i][1]);
}

var keys = Object.keys(intermediateObj);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++) {
     intermediateObj[keys[i]].splice(0,0,keys[i]);
     dest.push(intermediateObj[keys[i]]);
}
// Your required format
console.log(dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with ids and lists, i would recommend using an object.

In this way we can use the ids as indexes, which makes it easier to handle your data:

```js
//Original data
var originalData = [
  ['00011111', 'ADMIN'],
  ['00033333', 'ACTIVITY'],
  ['00022222', 'SUPPORT'],
  ['00011111', 'MEMBER'],
  ['00022222', 'MEMBER'],
  ['00033333', 'MEMBER']
];
//The new variable, which is in the form of an object
var newData = {};
//Loop through original data
originalData.forEach(function(dataPoints) {
  //If first time we encounter this id, create an array on newdata using the first element as key
  if (newData[dataPoints[0]] === void 0) {
    newData[dataPoints[0]] = [];
  }
  //Push secondary elements to our object, using the first element as key
  for (var index = 1; index < dataPoints.length; index++) {
    var dataPoint = dataPoints[index];
    newData[dataPoints[0]].push(dataPoint);
  }
});
//Output our new data object
console.log(newData);
//get data by id
console.log(newData["00033333"]);
```

Comment: I hope this is not giving the required response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [ [ '00011111', 'ADMIN' ],
  [ '00033333', 'ACTIVITY' ],
  [ '00022222', 'SUPPORT' ],
  [ '00011111', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00022222', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00033333', 'MEMBER' ] ]

const expected = [ [ '00011111', 'ADMIN', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00033333', 'ACTIVITY', 'MEMBER' ],
  [ '00022222', 'SUPPORT', 'MEMBER' ] ]
  
const collate = xs => Object.entries(xs.reduce(
  (a, [id, type]) => ({
    ...a,
    [id]: [...(a[id] || []), type ]
  })
, {})).map(
  ([id, types]) => [id, ...types]
)

console.log(collate(input))
```

This approach first reduces the original list to an object of the form:

```
{
  [id]: [...types]
}
```

Then iterates over that objects entries, collapsing each entry into a flat array.